# Onscroll is not called unless I handle wheel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component which is essentially a `div` containing a list of `div` elements (other mini components). The inner divs can change (add, delete) based on user interaction, therefore allowing the user to scroll if we have an overflow.

When showing this `div` and then scrolling with the mouse for the first time, the `onScroll` is called without problems. When I hide the div via css: `transform: translate3d`, then reopen the `div` the `onScroll` no longer works.

I added `onWheel` with an empty method to the `div` in the render function.

The scroll works!

Can someone please explain why when I added a listener to the wheel event it will cause the scroll event to fire? Also why is the scroll event is not getting fired in the first place?

I've tried to reproduce it in a fiddle, but it seems to work: 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/broonage/xkLmz5mz/)

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this issue in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Sure! I'll do that when I get a little minute. :)

Comment: try to hide it with `display: none` instead of `transform: translate3d`

Comment: Thanks, but we want a fancy animation. :)